# Set folder properties to show extra information

Tags: finder, folders, plist, finder-tag

I have seen that for certain folders such as **Pictures**, **Movies**, **Music**, show extra information in more columns when viewed in List View in Finder.

For e.g., if I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> click on one of the column names in any folders in List View, I can select the columns to view. In Pictures, I see that it includes two more properties `Dimensions` and `Resolution`.

Similarly, in **Music**, I can see `Authors`, `Title`, `Album` etc. I can see that on individual files in these folders, I can set such information using `xattr` on particular files. My question is, how do I mark a folder such that it shows such properties in the **List View**? and how do I tell which attributes to display?

I see from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/469197/how-do-you-add-dimension-columns-in-all-folders-on-a-mac/473697#473697) that a way to make some of the properties available was to temporarily change the folder name. Is there a better way? And is there a way to customize which properties are shown?

### What I have done so far:

- Renamed the directory to **Music**, and got the properties as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/469197/how-do-you-add-dimension-columns-in-all-folders-on-a-mac/473697#473697). Selected `Authors` as the property to keep.
- Then I renamed the directory back. It retained all the new columns
- Then I deleted the `.DS_store` from the folder. It still retained all the new columns.

> That is, the setting is not stored in the `.DS_Store`

- Then I checked the `mdls` output of the folder before and after renaming to **Music** and back. The only things changed were

  ```
  --- xx.lst  2018-08-16 02:51:45.000000000 -0700
  +++ xx1.lst 2018-08-16 02:52:25.000000000 -0700
  @@ -27,3 +27,9 @@
   kMDItemFSTypeCode                  = ""
   kMDItemInterestingDate_Ranking     = 2018-08-16 00:00:00 +0000
   kMDItemKind                        = "Folder"
  +kMDItemLastUsedDate                = 2018-08-16 09:52:14 +0000
  +kMDItemLastUsedDate_Ranking        = 2018-08-16 00:00:00 +0000
  +kMDItemUseCount                    = 3
  +kMDItemUsedDates                   = (
  +    "2018-08-15 22:00:00 +0000"
  +)
  ```

> So, it is not stored as an `xattr` in the directory.

- Moved it elsewhere. Moving it to a different folder did not cause the columns to be lost.

> So, the information is somehow carried with the directory entry.

- Renamed the folder to **Pictures**. It allowed me to add extra columns other than `Authors`. I chose `Resolution`. On renaming it back, it let me keep both `Authors` and `Resolution`

> So, in some way, the different properties are set differently, not based on a hard coding of particular folder types. That is, my folder is now neither **Music** nor **Pictures** in terms of the properties.

- Moved it to **iCloud**. I can still see the columns from the iCloud listing.
- Looked at the iCloud listing of my directory from another OSX system. The extra properties `Authors` and `Resolution` is no longer available.

> That is, iCloud is not storing these attributes. It is somehow stored in the individual system.